# Spring Boot Jetty Access log: logging server latency time

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jetty, embedded-jetty

I am using embedded(default way) jetty server for spring boot. I am trying to configure access log of jetty server by

I am using
`spring-boot-starter-jetty', version: '2.3.2.RELEASE'`
and spring boot is of the same version.

```
server.jetty.accesslog.append=false
server.jetty.accesslog.date-format=dd/MMM/yyyy:HH:mm:ss
server.jetty.accesslog.enabled=true
server.jetty.accesslog.extended-format=false
server.jetty.accesslog.file-date-format=dd/MMM/yyyy
server.jetty.accesslog.filename=/var/log/prod/access.log
server.jetty.accesslog.log-latency=true
server.jetty.accesslog.log-server=false
server.jetty.accesslog.retention-period=31
server.jetty.max-http-post-size=10MB
```

Neither `log-latecy` seems to work nor rolled up access log adhere to `file-data-format` config set in `application.properties`.
Please help

Comment: Jetty has it's own access / request logging, which doesn't use those configuration values or concepts.  It operates on a output format, which means you can put your various forms of latency logging anywhere you want in the output of the access log.  Perhaps you should look into using that mechanism, and not the overly simplified spring-boot specific abstraction.

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt Thanks for pointing it out. Are there any references for using the jetty configurations for a spring boot project.

Comment: Not really, also note that the spring-boot abstraction for access logging is not using the Jetty techniques, meaning your access log is missing many kinds of requests. (basically any requests that doesn't get dispatched to spring-boot is missing, which includes websocket, bad requests, proxy requests, error requests, etc ...)

Answer (score 0):

As of Spring 2.4.2 provides `WebServerFactoryCustomizer` to customize Jetty Servlet
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.0.M3/reference/html/howto-embedded-web-servers.html#howto-configure-jetty

Below solution can be used to support access log formats.

```
@Configuration
public class JettyWebServerCustomizer implements WebServerFactoryCustomizer<JettyServletWebServerFactory> {
    @Override
    public void customize(JettyServletWebServerFactory factory) {
        factory.getConfigurations();
        factory.addServerCustomizers(server -> {
            if (server.getRequestLog() instanceof CustomRequestLog) {
                CustomRequestLog existingRequestLog = (CustomRequestLog) server.getRequestLog();
                CustomRequestLog customRequestLog = new CustomRequestLog(existingRequestLog.getWriter(), "%{client}a - %u %t \"%r\" %s %O %{ms}T");
                server.setRequestLog(customRequestLog);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

CustomRequestLog also provides another constructor `CustomRequestLog(String file, String format)` which can be used to pass filename to support rolling file appenders.

Comment: Is it possible to do the same with properties file? like server.jetty.accesslog... ? i've tried but didn't worked.

Comment: @LucianoBrum No it is not possible right now