# Spring Access Log rotation by day

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jetty, embedded-jetty

I use an embedded Jetty server for a spring application. I tried to configure the access log to have one log file per day but all access log are added in one file.

In my application properties file :

```
server.jetty.accesslog.enabled=true
server.jetty.accesslog.append=true
server.jetty.accesslog.filename=/var/logs/access.log
server.jetty.accesslog.file-date-format=.yyyy-MM-dd
server.jetty.accesslog.retention-period=366
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That configuration is from an old, now deprecated, Request Log mechanism in Jetty.

For this old configuration, you MUST use the `yyyy_MM_dd` notation.

In other words ...

```
# This MUST contain `yyyy_MM_dd`
server.jetty.accesslog.filename=/var/logs/access_yyyy_MM_dd.log
# This MUST be `yyyy_MM_dd` (no other option is supported)
server.jetty.accesslog.file-date-format=yyyy_MM_dd
```

Jetty has moved to [`CustomRequestLog`](https://javadoc.io/static/org.eclipse.jetty/jetty-server/9.4.44.v20210927/org/eclipse/jetty/server/CustomRequestLog.html) which formats the log output, and using an implementation of [`RequestLog.Writer`](https://javadoc.io/static/org.eclipse.jetty/jetty-server/9.4.44.v20210927/org/eclipse/jetty/server/RequestLog.Writer.html) to determine where this formatted log is written to.

The most common `RequestLog.Writer` choice is [`Slf4jRequestLogWriter`](https://javadoc.io/static/org.eclipse.jetty/jetty-server/9.4.44.v20210927/org/eclipse/jetty/server/Slf4jRequestLogWriter.html) which writes the formatted logs to a named `slf4j-api` location, which allows you to use your logging implementation of choice (logback, java.util.logging, commons-logging, log4j1, log4j2, etc) to configure and specify rolling in that logging implementation (eg: by size, time, other event, etc).

The only other implementation of `RequestLog.Writer` is the [`AsyncRequestLogWriter`](https://javadoc.io/static/org.eclipse.jetty/jetty-server/9.4.44.v20210927/org/eclipse/jetty/server/AsyncRequestLogWriter.html), which has the same filename and fileDateFormat rules are stated above.

See past answer on spring + `CustomRequestLog` : https://stackoverflow.com/a/66079787/775715

Comment: Thanks, it works !